# How to handle multibyte numbers?

Tags: c, endianness

I'm trying to read binary data from a file. At the bytes 10-13 is a litte-endian binary-encoded number and I'm trying to parse it using only the information that the offset is 10 and the "size" is 4.

I've figured out I will have to do some binary shifting operations, but I'm not sure which byte goes where and how "far" and where it should be shifted.

Comment: You only have to do byte-shifting if you're on a big-endian machine, otherwise it's usable as it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know for certain the data is little endian, you can do something like:

```
int32 value = data[10] | (data[11] << 8) | (data[12] << 16) | (data[13] << 24);
```

This gives you a portable solution in case your code will run on both endian machines.

Comment: Yes, it works meanwhile. As said, I was unsure where to shift it and how far